# Observer on getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript

I need to observe obj.getBoundingClientRect() and update another DOM element on change of obj.

But `Observer.observe` is obsolete and `Object.prototype.watch()` is not recommended and mozilla specific.

The MDN suggest to use `Proxy`, but I can't see how can it help me. From my undestant, proxy only monitor a proxy object, not the object itself, so, when the object changes occur the proxy have no way to know.

Some one can give me a direction to solve this problem?

Comment: The object returned should be a native DOMRect object, and I'm guessing wildly you'd have to use an interval and check it manually? However, why do you need to do this in the first place, it sounds like an X/Y problem?

Comment: I don't need the DOMRect object itself, but I need the x,y,width,height values when it's updated.
The explanation is long... resuming when the object is rendered it may be hide, and when it is showed... it is not draw correctly.

Comment: Some alternatives (depending on what you want and need) are https://github.com/WICG/IntersectionObserver and https://github.com/wnr/element-resize-detector.